# How do I use a theme color from Angular Material prebuilt themes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I would like to use a specific color from the material theme in my css.

For example

```
.my_tab_group {
  border: 1px solid $some_color_from_theme;
}
```

Does Angular Material expose different color shades via some variable, so that I can use in my own .scss file (e.g., like using $some_color_from_theme above)?

Answer (score 8):

You must Import `~@angular/material/theming` in your sass file.

Then in your case you can write something like that:

```
.my_tab_group {
  border: 1px solid map-get($mat-light-theme-background, 'dividers');
}
```

Check the doc: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre Annic, From where can we find all the variables like the one above, "$mat-light-theme-background"

Comment: In `node_modules/@angular/material/theming` file.

Comment: This is good for the variables in palette, but it doesn't include the ones from the theme. How can I call the current theme and its composing colors?